# VueJS – Why can't I remove elements from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dom

I'm new to VueJS, and struggling to figure out how to do some very basic stuff. One specific thing I'm trying to do is modify an SVG on my page in a variety of ways, including deleting the children of a `<g>` element and replacing them with other children. Everything I'm trying won't work, and I can't figure out why.

Here's a *very* simplified version of the code...

**HTML**

```
<svg id="hz_svg" data-name="hz_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1600 1000">
  <g class="scale" width ="1400" style="fill: none; stroke: white; stroke-width: 2px;"> 
    <line x1="100" y1="1000" x2="1500" y2="1000"  />
    <g class="ticks">
      <line x1="100" y1="1000" x2="100" y2="980"/>
      <line x1="800" y1="1000" x2="800" y2="980"/>
      <line x1="1500" y1="1000" x2="1500" y2="980"/>
    </g>
  </g>
</svg>
```

**App.js**

```
const ticksEl = document.querySelector("#hz_svg .ticks");

createApp({
  methods: {
    renderTicks() {
      ticksEl.replaceChildren();
      console.log('REMOVED!!!');
    },
```

The strange thing here is that `console.log('REMOVED!!!')` runs, which means `ticksEl.replaceChildren();` ran. Yet, nothing happens to the elements on the page. My svg `<line>`s within `ticks` aren't removed. I know this isn't a problem with the JS itself, since I can easily remove the elements by including the `replaceChildren()` outside of createApp.

So what's going on here? Why can't I remove the elements?

Keep in mind I don't want to represent the line elements within the vueJS data if I don't have to.

Note: Running this code after `console.log('Removed!!!')` indicates that there are no lines anymore (children aren't there), even though I can clearly see them on the page: `console.log(ticksEl.children);`

Comment: Actually that is exactly what Vue is not meant to deal with.

Comment: With Vue you change app state, this app state is then rendered by the template. Manipulating the DOM directly is simply not how Vue works.

Comment: @ChrisG So functions within the vue App that manipulate the DOM directly don't work properly? If that's the case, how do I manipulate the DOM via functions in a coordinated way with the vue APP? What is a reasonable alternative here?

Comment: Again, you manipulate the state instead, i.e. a bunch of variables in your Vue component code. The template is supposed to turn any state into its HTML equivalent, so you need to come up with a suitable data structure for the state. For this task you'd use conditional rendering, like `<line v-if="showTicks" x1="100" y1="1000" x2="100" y2="980"/>` where `showTicks` is either true or false. Setting it to false will no longer render the <line>, i.e. remove it. This is a basic and essential part of the docs: https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html

Comment: @ChrisG So if I wanted to, via a function (method I guess), remove all existing content within an element and replace that content in one fell-swoop, how would I do that? The removal/replacement would not be triggered by anything on the page directly, but instead triggers when some computed values change.

Comment: You render everything conditionally based on one of the computed values for example.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend first reading more about the essentials of Vue and similar frameworks. Below just an example of how one might do something similar to what you are trying to achive:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#container',
  template: `<div>
<button v-on:click="removeShapes">Remove Shapes</button>
<label><input type="radio" name="fill" value="red" v-on:change="saveFill" :checked="currentFill === 'red'"> Red</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="fill" value="blue" v-on:change="saveFill" :checked="currentFill === 'blue'"> Blue</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="fill" value="green" v-on:change="saveFill" :checked="currentFill === 'green'"> Green</label>
<button v-on:click="addShape">Add Shape</button>
  <svg id="hz_svg" data-name="hz_svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 1600 1000" width="1600" height="1600"  preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin slice">
  <template v-for="shape of this.shapesHTML">
    <g v-html="shape" />
  </template>
</svg>
</div>`,
  data: {
    shapes: [
      { type: 'circle', cx: 30, cy: 50, r: 30, fill: 'red' },
      { type: 'circle', cx: 70, cy: 50, r: 30, fill: 'green' },
      { type: 'circle', cx: 110, cy: 50, r: 30, fill: 'blue' },
    ],
    currentFill: 'red',
  },
  computed: {
    shapesHTML() {
      return this.shapes.map((shape) => {
        let attributes = (({ type, ...attributes }) => attributes)(shape)
        let htmlAttributes = Object.entries(attributes).map(([key, attribute]) => `${key}="${attribute}"`)
        return `<${shape.type} ${htmlAttributes.join(' ')} />`
      })
    }
  },
  methods: {
    removeShapes() {
      this.shapes = []
    },
    addShape() {
      this.shapes = [ ...this.shapes, {
        type: 'circle',
        cy: 50,
        cx: 20 + ((this.shapes.length + 1) * 30),
        r: 30,
        fill: this.currentFill,
      } ]
    },
    saveFill(e) {
      this.currentFill = e.target.value
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```